# Why are links at the top, view counts, tags, comments, etc. italicized?

Tags: support, user-interface

Starting yesterday, almost everything on Maths.SE (and other SE sites, too, I might add) is italicized:

[image]

This behaviour occurs in Chrome (30.0) as well as Opera (12.16). It does not seem to occur in Firefox (25.0.1).

Refreshing, clearing cache, incognito browsing, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by something that deleted the "Arial Regular" font from my system.

Heaps of other people have had this issue as well, so I suspect it was an erroneous Windows update somewhere.

Downloading and installing the [EU Expansion Font Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16083) re-introduced the Arial Regular font, and fixed the problem.

(One can check if the Arial Regular font is present by navigating to `Control Panel > Fonts > Arial` (at least on Windows 7).)

Comment: Or just bring up the Character Map; on my system this is actually quicker.